# Correct usage of "nor"?

Tags: or-nor

I was wondering if I am using *nor* correctly in the following sentence or I should replace it by *or*?

> Adding this additional functionality does not increase the manufacturing cost of the product *nor* the manufacturing time significantly.

I appreciate your helps in advance.

Comment: Using *nor* in the sentence structure, at that position, is to condone the use of *double negatives*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by pure logic, I think you should replace it by *'or'*.

*'Nor'* may seem to get the meaning across, but the key here is your usage of *'does not'*.

The correct structures are:

> Adding this additional functionality **does not increase (either)** the manufacturing cost of the product ***or*** the manufacturing time significantly.

and

> Adding this additional functionality **increases neither** the manufacturing cost of the product ***nor*** the manufacturing time significantly.

Comment: The use of nor is probably declining, even in its core domain of coordinating two negative phrases.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really keen on the 'nor', then perhaps another way to utilize it would be, "Adding this additional functionality neither increases the manufacturing cost of the product, nor the manufacturing time significantly."

I was taught to see 'neither' and 'nor' as best friends that can't be parted, with 'nor' always following 'neither' in a sentence.

Hope that helps.